# Can you deliberately damage RAM using pointers?

Tags: c, hardware, c++

Can one deliberately cause physical damage to RAM using C++ and its implementation of pointers?

What about segmentation faults? Can they cause any damage?

Example: trying to access a non-existent address.

Comment: If it's actually RAM, then no.  If it's an IO device, writing the wrong things, the wrong timings, can lead to problems -- for example moving a disk head back and forth continuously.  Or EEPROM, which has a limited number of writes.  None of this is language-specific, and is one of the principal reasons for having "kernel" mode: only a small trusted amount of code has access to hardware.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify: Why do you think is the programming language relevant? Why specifically C++? Or C? In the end the CPU executes machine code and it makes no difference from what programming language it was generated. Depending on your reasoning you might want to remove the C and C++ tags.

Comment: Please note that "seg faults" is a nonsense term in the context of embedded systems - they cannot occur. Seg faults can only happen on hosted systems that implement signal.h, which in practice means *nix-like systems. Windows for example calls these "access violations" but they aren't handled through signal.h there. Some embedded systems may have similar mechanisms in case they have a somewhat MMU which supports virtual memory and separating executable address space from data address space (for example Power PC, but this is not a concern in Cortex M or in even lower-tier MCUs).

Comment: Depending on the hardware, you can certainly cause physical damage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_poke

Comment: @MattS There's also the legendary [HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire_(computing)) instruction of MC6800, but that one just like  your examples has nothing to do with _RAM memory access_ either, but in this case by executing an illegal/undocumented opcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, no. It isn't possible to physically damage the memory from software. (Even something like [row hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer) causes no physical damage.) However, it is easy to corrupt the contents of memory, which will cause other software (operating system, other applications) to fail to operate correctly to varying degrees.

A segmentation fault is an exception (e.g., bus error or interrupt) generated by the MMU when it detects an access violation -- either the virtual address isn't present in physical memory or the permissions are not correct for the attempted operation. When this occurs, the physical memory is not accessed at all, so again, no damage is possible.

Comment: Setting up the prescaler clock to flash incorrectly and then writing to it does cause extra wear, I believe. Similarly, it is easy to write a bug writing to the same cell over and over, destroying the flash. You might want to change this to "damage the _RAM_ memory"

Comment: @Lundin: The OP has already specified that we're talking about RAM. And sure, wear-out can be greatly accelerated in memories that have wear mechanisms, but to be honest, I don't consider that to be "physical damage".

Answer (score 1):

Seg faults are simply a trap to the OS triggered by the Memory Management Unit. Hardware-wise, it's no different than accessing a paged-out area of virtual memory. This happens (probably) millions of time in a day in a modern OS.

As @drmoishepippik commented, there are bugs in some hardware platforms where repeatedly writing to a single memory location or specific patterns of repeated writes can damage RAM but this is difficult to execute at user-level as the code is being interrupted by hardware back to the OS frequently enough to avoid these situations.